# Parameter subscription must conform to pattern ^projects/[^/]+subscriptions/[^/]+$

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

.I am trying to create a data fusion pipeline which fetches data from pub sub and the used projection to convert message into string (as told by you) and thens ave it to GCS.

howeer,its giving me error: Parameter subscription must conform to pattern ^projects/[^/]+subscriptions/[^/]+$

I am using correct topic and subsctiption name projects/test/subscriptions/dataFusionSubscribe projects/test/topics/DataFusionTopic

Comment: Can you copy the full command you're trying to run here?

Comment: I have used data fusion. I selected real-time pipeline in the dropdown and then selected pubsub as a source with all the details..i added above details thereafter

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to include the full subscription and topic name in the config, you only need to provide project id as test, subscription id as dataFusionSubscribe, and topic as DataFusionTopic
[Attached is a screenshot showing the config for the Pubsub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBoe2.png)